# helm find projectile file: how to view the file content when choose the file?

Tags: projectile, helm-projectile

when run the command of helm-find-projectile-file, it will show a file lists in the mini buffer, and then I can use up and down key to select the file I want to view. But is it possible to view the file content when I select a file without press the "Enter" key? if press the Enter key, then I have to get back the helm session. I just want to use up and down key to go through each file, and then let emacs show the file content immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to press <kbd>C-j</kbd> or <kbd>C-z</kbd>to see the content of the *thing* under the selection.

Comment: I am using spacemacs, ctrl+j just move the item down, just like key of down array.

Comment: Try `C-z`. It is `helm-execute-presistent-action`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: C-z pop up a HELM Action:  It has a menu list, like [f1] Find file etc.

Comment: Add `C-z` or whatever key you want for `helm-execute-persistent-action` to `helm-map` first `(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-z") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `helm-follow-mode`, it should do the trick.